# Hyperlink doesn't working in iMacros 2021 but does in iMacros version 12

Tags: vba, hyperlink, imacros

I've written a macro in iMacros version 12and it works exactly like a user navigating through several pages in a application.

I'm trying to update the macro to work in iMacros version 2021.

The macro logs into the application, navigates to a specific page.  On that page the macro enters a "ref id" in a specific field and presses the search key.  The application displays the results on the next page.  So far so good.

The first field on the results page is a record number as a hyperlink.  In version 12, the macro clicks on the hyperlinked record number and continues the process.

In version 2021, the cursor remains as an arrow and does not change to the "finger".  This is the point I'm stuck at.  iMacros 2021 does not allow me to click on the hyperlinked record number.

Has anyone seen this behavior before in 2 different iMacros versions?  If so, were you able to resolve the issue and how did you resolve it.

I have never seen anything like this before.  Here is the code that I'm trying to execute to click on the hyperlink in version 2021.

```
IM = "CODE:"
IM = IM + "TAB T=1" + vbNewLine
IM = IM + "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + vbNewLine
IM = IM + "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + vbNewLine
IM = IM + "TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:" & vLetters4(Y) + vbNewLine
```

Thanks in advance for your help......

Comment: "*doesn't working*" = "Doesn't sound[ing] very English", I'm afraid... :wink: // Could you mention the exact iMB v2021/v14.x Version...? // Issue looks like a Bug or Debug/Troubleshooting one to me, won't be "easy" to solve with the simplistic Q&A Format on this Site,  => might be a "better fit" on the iMacros Forum... // What is `vLetters4(Y)` yielding for Output...? // How is this `Y` Var defined/declared...? (Or is it the literal "Y" String...?) // Do you also get the same Behaviour using a minimal pure '.iim' Script with the `TXT` Attribute hard-coded...?

Comment: @chivracq.........Good to hear from you.  I didn't think you were following questions here.  I will post this in the iMacros forum with more info when I have some time.  I'm juggling 3 or 4 projects at this time.  I ran into this roadblock and haven't gotten back to it.  My main project takes priority over everything else so that is why I haven't responded.  I realize this wasn't a lot of info on the issue I was having but I was hoping someone else may have had a similar issue and would say try this.  Thanks for your help..

Comment: Oh...!, good, you're "alive", ah-ah...! Yeah, well, there is not much "Knowledge" about iMacros on this Site, and I'm mostly the only one answering Threads, when the Quality is "not too bad", ah-ah...! // Then yep, start your Thread in the [iMacros Scripting Interface' Sub-Forum](https://forum.imacros.net/viewforum.php?f=8), I would say... But if it's a Bug, it probably won't get fixed, iMacros was announced EOL [a few days ago](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=32085)...

Comment: @chivracq...........I saw the message about iMacros EOL.....the company I work for is starting to look at alternatives.  We have a core group of people that develop iMacro macros and then distribute them field users (who use the player version).  Some of these macros are used by 150 + users and some are used multiple times a day.  So the EOL message got everyone's attention

Comment: Yeah well, feel free to post your Story in the "EOL" Thread I linked to, or on the 'Progress' Forum where the same Announcement was also posted... I'm the only one "complaining" about this EOL sad Decision until now, I could use "some Support", ah-ah...!